# Django: How do I return properties from a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django

I am making a simple web app that consists of the following models/views:

```
# Models
from django.db import models

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Room_Exit(models.Model):
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    secret = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.direction

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    environment = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    secret = models.BooleanField()
    outdoors = models.BooleanField()
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    exits = models.ManyToManyField(Room_Exit)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Views
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from wb.models import Area, Room_Exit, Room

def arealist(request):
    areas = Area.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render_to_response('areas/arealist.html', {'areas': areas})

def roomlist(request, area_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(Area, pk=area_id)
    return render_to_response('areas/roomlist.html', {'area': a})

def roomdetail(request, area_id, room_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(Area, pk=area_id)
    r = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=room_id)
    return render_to_response('areas/roomdetail.html', {'room': r})
```

I am trying to make a template that will print out the properties of a Room. I am able to print out every property except when it comes to the ManyToManyField. There is a room created in the database that has 2 Room_Exits. Here is the template:

```
<h1>{{ room.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>
        ID: {{ room.id }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Description: {{ room.description }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Environment: {{ room.environment }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Secret room: {{ room.secret }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Outdoor room: {{ room.outdoors }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Area: {{ room.area }}
    </li>
    <li>
        Exits: 
        {% for exits in room.room_exit.all %}
            {{ exits }}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
    </ul>
```

I am trying to loop through the Room_Exits of the Room, but all it gives back is
Exits:
without anything being returned. Can anyone give me an idea as to what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `room.room_exit.all` to `room.exits.all` in your template